# Matplotlib - Axes collision warning when setting aspect ratio

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, warnings

I am using `matplotlib` to plot a hexbin. As a simple example-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize = 15, cmap='inferno')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis() # To make top left corner as origin

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

I get the following warning-

"MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance."

I think it is due to the line-

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

How can I use different arguments in this case. The version of `matplotlib`is `2.1.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you want to create a new axes anyways. So don't use `plt.axes()` here. Instead **g**et the **c**urrent **a**xes in the usual way (`plt.gca()`) and use any of its methods.

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```